# Are the contents of ethereum storage private?

Tags: security, privacy, database

I know that the code is public, but is the contents of storage private?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Solidity functions - private visibility](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6547/solidity-functions-private-visibility)

Answer (score 3):

The contents are private only in the sense that other contracts can't read them if you set them private, but otherwise everything is public. All nodes need to be able to process the data so they also have access to all the data (including private variables).

More reading: [Store secret data in contract](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13681/store-secret-data-in-contract) (and its duplicate)

Comment: You should answer a question when it has been closed. Your answer should be removed.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Closing a questions does not make an answer invalid or wrong. If the question was closed when I opened it I couldn't have answered it anymore.

Comment: The question was closed and voted off the forum. That does make your answer invalid (obviously). A question is valid or invalid. It does not change its validity: if I say a brick is red, it was a red before I said it was a brick, my saying the colour does not change the colour. You answered an invalid question. You clearly think you can answer an invalid question but others cannot as if somehow your answer is better than others. As I said, your answer should be removed. If it is not removed, this forum is simply discriminating against other people.

Comment: You are entitled to your opinion. You can flag the answer for moderator attention if you feel that necessary.