# Inspecting private variables of a contract

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, private

In the solidity documentation, it is written

> Everything that is inside a contract is visible to all external
>   observers. Making something private only prevents other contracts from
>   accessing and modifying the information, but it will still be visible
>   to the whole world outside of the blockchain.

I also read [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2624/private-info-on-ethereum) answer. 
Can anyone suggest a step to step process of inspecting private variables of a smart contract using the Ethereum data I stored on my system?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you have the source code for the contract in question, it's a two-step process:

1. Determine, from the source code, the location(s) in storage that you're interested in.
2. Call the `eth_getStorageAt` JSON-RPC method (perhaps multiple times) to retrieve the data.

Two of my blog posts might help:

- [Understanding Ethereum Smart Contract Storage](https://programtheblockchain.com/posts/2018/03/09/understanding-ethereum-smart-contract-storage/) explains how state variables are mapped to storage locations.
- [Making Smart Contracts With Public Variables](https://programtheblockchain.com/posts/2018/01/02/making-smart-contracts-with-public-variables/) shows how to call `eth_getStorageAt` from JavaScript to retrieve data from the contract.

If you do *not* have the source code, there are still a few things you can do. You can try to read the bytecode directly, you can use a disassembler to try to reconstruct the original source, or you can debug transactions to see where data is being written.